how to make a button submit the form value to the server but not refresh the page?
I've made an html button which gets triggered when I change the select tag's value. I just want to send information to the server and retrieve the corresponding data back, and use it on the same page I'm on. But as soon as I trigger the button, it either doesn't submit it if I set type = 'button' or sends the data but refresh the page when I set the type = 'submit'. refreshing the page is not something I really want, so how can I set it to just receive and process the data instead of refreshing the page too.
Here's my button's code-
<form id="selectedScript">
      <label for="script">Choose a script:</label>
      <select name="script" id="script">
        <option value="main" selected>Main</option>
        <option value="main2">Main2</option>
      </select>
      <button hidden form="selectedScript" formaction="/playground/scriptBtn" formmethod="post" formtarget="_self" id="scriptBtn" type="button"></button>
    </form>

here's my JS script file's code -
selectedScript.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (
    confirm(
      "Are you sure you want to change the script? This will clear the current text from input box"
    ) == true
  ) {
    inputBox.value = "";
    outputBox.value = "";
    document.getElementById('scriptBtn').click(); //this is where button gets triggered.
  }
});

here's the code from behind, Right now I am not sending any data back, but just consoling the request object, to see everything works. -
router.route('/playground/scriptBtn')
.post((req, res) =>{
    console.log(req)
    res.end()
})

also note that the button is actually in /playground.ejs file and is making action on /playground/scriptBtn url. So when it refreshes, it goes to a url which doesn't render any html but registers a post request on it.
Thanks in advance.

A form is a link, you can't submit the form and stay on the current page. You can send data to the server using an AJAX request, see Fetch API to send data and stay on the current page.

Does this answer your question? How do I post form data with fetch api?

You don't need a button to achieve this. You can call an ajax call from inside the change event listener.


selectedScript.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to change the script? This will clear the current text from input box") == true) {
    callAPI();
  }
});
function callAPI() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("feild1", "feild1 value");
  formData.append("feild2", "feild2 value");

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // this.response => this is the API response you can process and use
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "/playground/scriptBtn", true);
  xhttp.send(formData);
}
<form id="selectedScript">
  <label for="script">Choose a script:</label>
  <select name="script" id="script">
    <option value="main" selected>Main</option>
    <option value="main2">Main2</option>
  </select>
  <button hidden form="selectedScript" formaction="/playground/scriptBtn" formmethod="post" formtarget="_self" id="scriptBtn" type="button" onclick="loadDoc()"></button>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>



If you want to call a GET API just change the POST to GET,


selectedScript.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to change the script? This will clear the current text from input box") == true) {
    callAPI();
  }
});
function callAPI() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      // this.response => this is the API response you can process and use
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/playground/scriptBtn?field1=value1&field2=value2", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
<form id="selectedScript">
  <label for="script">Choose a script:</label>
  <select name="script" id="script">
    <option value="main" selected>Main</option>
    <option value="main2">Main2</option>
  </select>
  <button hidden form="selectedScript" formaction="/playground/scriptBtn" formmethod="post" formtarget="_self" id="scriptBtn" type="button" onclick="loadDoc()"></button>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>




If you need to use a Fetch API. Find full documentation here.


selectedScript.addEventListener("change", () => {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to change the script? This will clear the current text from input box") == true) {
    callAPI();
  }
});
async function callAPI() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("feild1", "feild1 value");
  formData.append("feild2", "feild2 value");
  const response = await fetch("/playground/scriptBtn", {
    method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    body: formData
  });
  return response.json();
}
<form id="selectedScript">
  <label for="script">Choose a script:</label>
  <select name="script" id="script">
    <option value="main" selected>Main</option>
    <option value="main2">Main2</option>
  </select>
  <button hidden form="selectedScript" formaction="/playground/scriptBtn" formmethod="post" formtarget="_self" id="scriptBtn" type="button" onclick="loadDoc()"></button>
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>




Thanks for the solution. Can I do the same thing using fetchAPI?

If you meant get data with fetch. Edited the code. If you meant GET API that is also added in the answer. Hope it works! If it works, please upvote and accept the answer.

FetchAPI is the way to go, XHR requests can work, but lack several functionalities of the fetchAPI
